# url_title codeigniter showing underscores instead of hyphens

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, seo

Hi I am trying to insert my article title in database in the following format `this-is-a-new-title` for the input `This is a new Title`. For this I have written :

```
$title = $this->input->post('topic_title');
$topic_slug_title = url_title($title,'-',TRUE);
```

But the `echo $topic_slug_title` shows titles like `this_is_a_new_title`. Why the underscores are added wherein I have given hyphens ?

Comment: use str_replace http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_replace.asp

Comment: Can't I do it with codeigniter `url_title()` only ? according to the documentation,second parameter is word delimiter

Comment: better get in lowercase string and use default url_title()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution. Just leave the second parameter as default,add the third parameter. That is:

```
$title = $this->input->post('topic_title');
$topic_slug_title = url_title($title,TRUE,TRUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

don't use the third parameter, use it like this

```
$title = $this->input->post('topic_title');
```

`$topic_slug_title = strtolower(url_title($title));`

Answer (score 0):

don't use second and third parameter, write like this:

```
    **$title = $this->input->post('topic_title');  
    $topic_slug_title = url_title($title);**
```